# Change Query String using HTACCESS?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How do I change the query from

```
https://www.example.com/page.php?foo=bar
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/page.php?foo=something
```

just using htaccess ?

I had tried :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo\=bar$ [QSR]
RewriteRule page\.php\?foo\=bar$ page\.php\?foo\=baz [L,R=301]
```

not not working, testing it in the online htaccess tester -- https://htaccess.mwl.be/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo=bar$
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ page.php?foo=baz [L,R=301]
```

Because the querystring is not part of the RewriteRule test.

Comment: I am getting `page.php?foo=baz?foo=bar` . ie, the original query string gets appended to the modified query string.